# QUdpSocket connect to readyRead no effect after disconnecting

Tags: c++, qt, udp, qt-signals, qt-slot

I'm trying to create an UDPLogger.

When I connect the first time to readyRead I get data over UDP.

```
connect(m_socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &UDP::readData);
```

when I stop to get the signal readyRead with disconnect which works fine and reconnect, my slot will never executed. I looked at the response from the connect and the reconnect function, but they are always true. This is my slot:

```
void UDP::readData()
```

Why I cannot reconnect this signal/slot? The UDP object runs in a second thread.

Here is a small project, which shows the same behavior:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q5fc8kkwrygicef/AAC0f91GIo8lWwqLG_Xpf20Ja?dl=0

the udp object will be created in the mainwindow.cpp constructor.

Here is my sender of the udp data:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/skz1cd4lvtgg5vp/AAAbRarhY0VDWD-Dk9cR45iGa?dl=0

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Now I added a minimal example